# Custom Component extending JavaFX 8 TreeTableView

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a class MyTreeTableView extending TreeTableView

I have implmented few methods to populate the treeview by passing an observable list in my derived class, which is not available in the original TreeTableView. Other than that there are no additional functionalities.

I am able to use this class and it works as intended when coding in Java

i.e

```
MyTreeTableView localtree = new MyTreeTableView(new TreeItem<>());
localtree.setItems(myobservedList);
```

If I add this instance to a scene everything works like a standard TreeTableView.. To add this instance to the scene I have to do this on the Java side.

I have to make my class MyTreeTableView in to a custom FXML component so that its accessible using scene builder for easy drag and drop.

Before venturing on to the custom component side of FXML, I tried to assign the `localtreetable` to a standard Java FX 8 TreeTableView which is defined in the FXML and is part of the existing scene.

I did the following

```
localtreetable.getColumns().addAll(col1,col2);
        localtreetable.setShowRoot(false);
        localtreetable.setItems(myobservedList);
        JavaFX8TreeTableView.setRoot(localtreetable.getRoot());
        col1 = (TreeTableColumn<Object, String>) JavaFX8TreeTableView.getColumns().get(0);
        col2 = (TreeTableColumn<Object, String>) JavaFX8TreeTableView.getColumns().get(1);

//setCellValueFactory and CellFactories for col1 and col2 after this.
```

Here `col1` and `col2` are defined in the FXML and they are the columns of the  `JavaFX8TreeTableView` which is also defined in the FXML.

With this hack, the JavaFX8TreeTableView shows up on the UI with the data populated in the 
`localtreetable` object. However the UI is not correctly intended and the tree view is messed up. When I say messed up, the tree is in proper order, but the > is placed on the 4th letter of a tree item and a click on the arrow doesn't expand or close the tree item, you have to click it at some other location for it to expand and close it.
[image]
My first issue is how do I transpose values from `localtreetable` to a JavaFx8TreeTableView, so that I can populate values to an already defined TreeTableView

Answer (score 0):

When migrating to Java8, there is bug in the JavaFX 2.2 while populating the TreeItem, branchExpand and branchCollapse events, some how there are empty TreeItem are getting added up. You can fix that bug by explicitly writing 
setGraphic(null);
setText(null);
in the updateItem function

public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

```
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
                if (
                    !getTreeItem().isLeaf()&&getTreeItem().getParent()!= null
                ){
                    setContextMenu(addMenu);
                }
            }
        }
```

Refer 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-view.htm#BABDEADA